# Display images in grid view of View pager

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-viewpager

I am working on image gallery for which i have made use of ViewPager addon api. I am loading images from a specific folder in sdcard. My goal is to display only 9 images per screen in ViewPager, which i am not able to achieve. The below code is the mainactivity.

```
public class AndroidSwipeGalleryActivity extends Activity {

private int size;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.image_gallery);

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/xxxxxxx/images");

    if (file.exists()) {

        size = file.listFiles().length;

        System.out.println("=====File exists====Length is====="+size);

        double quo = (double)size/9;

        System.out.println("====Dividing by 9====" + quo);

        size = (int) Math.ceil(quo);

        System.out.println("===Math===== "+size);

    } else {

        System.out.println("======File does not exists====");

    }

    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this);
    adapter.setScrCount(size);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

}
```

}

The Pager Adapter and Image adapter are in the below class:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private TextView tv;

private GridView gv;

private int scrCount;

private int count;

public int imageCount;

private Cursor cursor;

private int columnIndex;

private Activity act;

public MyPagerAdapter(Activity act) {

    this.act = act;

}

public int getCount() {

    return getScrCount();

}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard

    String uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;

    String condition = uri + " like '%/beverlyhills/images%'";

    cursor = act.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, condition, null, null);

    count = cursor.getCount();

    System.out.println("Cursor count::::"+count);

    // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID

    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < getScrCount() ; i++) {

            if (count > 9) {

                if (position == i) {

                int num = 0;

                num = count - 9;

                count = num;

                imageCount = 9;

                }

            } else {

                imageCount = count;

            }
    }

    resId = R.layout.number_one;

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    tv = (TextView) collection.findViewById(R.id.swipeTitleTextView);

    tv.setText("Swipe Gallery");

    gv = (GridView) collection.findViewById(R.id.galleryGridView);

    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(collection.getContext(), imageCount);

    gv.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

     // Set up a click listener
    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Get the data location of the image
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = act.managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // Return all rows
                    null,
                    null);
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            // Get image filename
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            // Use this path to do further processing, i.e. full screen display

            System.out.println("=====Image Path:::::"+imagePath);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void startUpdate(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public int getScrCount() {
    return scrCount;
}

public void setScrCount(int scrCount) {
    this.scrCount = scrCount;
}


private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int count;

    public ImageAdapter(Context ctx, int count) {

        this.count = count;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return count;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          ImageView picturesView;
          if (convertView == null) {
              picturesView = new ImageView(act);
              // Move cursor to current position
              cursor.moveToPosition(position);
              // Get the current value for the requested column

              int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);

              // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
              picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                      MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
              picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
              picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
              picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
          }
          else {
              picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
          }
          return picturesView;
    }

}

}
```

The problem is I am able to load the images and display them on screen but not able to display exactly 9 images per screen. Please go through the code, it's not complex.

Answer (score 1):

i have create the other demo example of view pager to manage the page and also load images. follow the steps wise, its perfectly works..

its a Pager adapter and mDataHolder(List of images) and 
Set the property of gridview `android:numColumns="3"`

```
    private int size;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int MATRIX = 9;


public int getCount() {
        int size = 0;
        if (mDataHolder != null)
            modular = mDataHolder.get_Listholder().size() % MATRIX;
        if (modular != 0)
            size++;

        return ((mDataHolder.get_Listholder().size()) / MATRIX) + size;
    }



    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int pageIndex) {

        mRelativeLayoutInflater = (RelativeLayout) mMasterFragmentActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.member_pager_adapter, container, false);
        mGridView = (GridView) mRelativeLayoutInflater.findViewById(R.id.member_gridView_list);
```

`Calculation of pages`<

```
        size = MATRIX;
        start = pageIndex * MATRIX;
        end = 0;
        int temp = 0;

        if ((start + MATRIX) < mDataHolder.get_Listholder().size()) {
            end = start + MATRIX;
        } else {
            temp = mDataHolder.get_Listholder().size() - start;
            end = start + temp;
            size = temp;
        }
```

> ... and then pass the variable to gridview adapter to set other content in pager.

```
        mAdapterMember = new AdapterMember(mContext, start, end, size);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapterMember);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(mRelativeLayoutInflater);
        return mRelativeLayoutInflater;
    }
```

Below Manage pages variables also use the Gridview adapter to set the postion.
when the set page content position to be like `(start + position)`

```
private class AdapterMember extends BaseAdapter {

    private ViewHolder mViewHolder;
    private Context mContext;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int size;

    private AdapterMember(Context mContext, int start, int end, int size) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (size > 0)
            return size;
        else 
            return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if (mMemberListVO.getMember().size() > 0)
            return mMemberListVO.getMember().get(position);
        else 
            return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_member_list, null);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            mViewHolder.mImageViewMemberPhoto = (NetworkImageView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.row_member_list_imageView_person);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewMemberName = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.row_member_list_textview_person_name);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewMemberDesignation = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.row_member_list_textview_person_designation);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewMemberAddress = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.row_member_list_textview_person_address);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewMemberNotification = (TextView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.row_member_list_imageview_msg_notification);
            convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } 


         mViewHolder.mTextViewMemberName.setText(mDataHolder.get_Listholder().get(start + position) .get(DBHelper.mFieldMember_First_Name)
                + getString(R.string.double_quate_with_space)
                + mDataHolder.get_Listholder(). get(start + position).get(DBHelper.mFieldMember_Last_Name));

        mViewHolder.mTextViewMemberDesignation.setText(mDataHolder.get_Listholder().get(start + position)
                .get(DBHelper.mFieldMember_Occupation));

        mViewHolder.mTextViewMemberAddress.setText(mDataHolder.get_Listholder().get(start + position) .get(DBHelper.mFieldMember_Block_No)
                + "," + getString(R.string.double_quate_with_space)
                + mDataHolder.get_Listholder().get(start + position).get(DBHelper.mFieldMember_House_No) + ","
                + getString(R.string.double_quate_with_space)
                + mDataHolder.get_Listholder().get(start + position).get(DBHelper.mFieldMember_Home_Address) + ".");

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private NetworkImageView mImageViewMemberPhoto;
        private TextView mTextViewMemberName, mTextViewMemberDesignation, mTextViewMemberAddress,
                mTextViewMemberNotification;
    }
}
```

its perfectly Working with your requirement...
The problem is solve to load the images and display them on screen its display exactly 9 images per screen.