# Create a paged GridView

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android, android-gridview

I need to create a paged `GridView` where each page contains some elements from a list, like launcher applications do to show the installed apps.The `GridView` only contains the elements that have enough space on the screen to be shown and the remaining apps are added in the `GridView` of the next `Fragment`. 
I've found many examples that explain how to implement this, for example http://shrikantsonarblogs.blogspot.com/2013/07/gridview-with-viewpager-like-android.html or [Display images in grid view of View pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722340/display-images-in-grid-view-of-view-pager), but in all of these examples the number of rows and columns are fixed values. 
Is there a way to make these values "dynamic" by dividing the dimensions of the `ViewPager` by the dimensions of a child `View` (supposed they are all the same size, but I have to measure the first one)?

If what I want to achieve is not clear, an example can be the app drawer of the CyanogenMod Trebuchet launcher, with the only difference that I don't need it to display installed apps.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this problem?